# Set of number Where any subset has a unique sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that my qustion sounds like a duplicate like
[set-with-k-subset-unique-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130431/set-with-k-subset-unique-sum)

and others but what i really looking for is that each element in the set is increased by a constant C.
for example if i have a set S = {3, 4, 5} its obvious that the constant C = 1 and every subset of the set S has a unique sum, put the problem that i could get a set has a length bigger than 3. 
and my goal is to get infinite set of number that satisfies my rule, if there is a finite set what is the maximum length ?

Comment: What about $\{2^n\}_{n=0}^\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a set  of form  $\{a,a+C,a+2C,a+3C\}$, each subset does not have a unique sum. Also, any set of the form you want has a subset of this form, if it has more than 3 elements. So, 3 elements is the biggest you can get of your form.

Comment: i was afraid that someone is going to tell me this, but why 3 is the biggest length i can get ?

Comment: Well, any set(of your type) bigger than 4 elements has a subset of your type of size 4. If you add the biggest and the smallest and the middle ones you get the same sum(for one of size 4).

Comment: In a sense arithmetic progressions are the worst sets for unique  sums

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to talk about the existence of pairs which differ by one.  Note that I could write your set as $\{3, 5, 4\}$, in which case the second element listed on the computer screen is not increased by 1.

For a set $S$, for all $x$ belonging to $S$, there exists a $y$ belonging to $S$, such that $(x-y)=c$.  The doesn't work, since for $3$ there doesn't exist such a $y$.  I guess maybe

> "For a set $S$, for all $x$ belonging to $S$, there exists a y belonging to S, such that $|(x-y)|=1$"

I don't understand your problem otherwise.